# Outlets that work only part of the time

Tags: bedroom

In one of the bedrooms there are two outlets that work part of the time if you plug something in you might have to wiggle the plug to make it work. The bedroom next to it the closet light does the same thing it will flicker on and off if you're wiggling the plug in the other room.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a loose connection in the junction box holding the outlet that works when wiggled. It may be a poor screw connection on the outlet, a bad wirenut connection or even a bad connection internal to the outlet itself.

The power in the bedroom is likely being fed from that bad connection.

Turn off the breaker that controls that outlet. Remove the outlet cover. Test the wires with a non-contact tester to make sure they are not live. Check all connections (screws, wirenuts). If nothing looks loose, replace the outlet itself, wiring up the same way as before. Mark each wire before removing it from the outlet so you can attach them to the new outlet in the same way. Replace cover. Turn on power.

If any of this seems daunting, you probably need help from someone with more experience.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bad connection or a broken wire. The outlet that works when wiggled is where the problem is. With the power turned off at the breaker remove the cover plate and then the 2 screws holding the outlet in place gently pull the outlet out. If the wires are pushed into the back stabs this is a very common failure and the side screws can be used to anchor all the wires in place. A short piece of scrap wire or a small screwdriver can usually release the wire from the back stab. If one of the wires are broken it will need to be stripped and re connected. My preference is to pig tail the blacks together using a short piece of black wire going to the outlet brass colored screw and the same with the white using a piece of white going to the silver colored screw and last the grounds but this should have already have been done.